# error: [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i am getting error while i run the command node query.js in hypeledger-samples  fabcar example.

root@ubcourt:/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript# node query.js

Wallet path: /home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
2019-08-03T08:45:31.027Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied

2019-08-03T08:45:31.028Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied

2019-08-03T08:45:31.040Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied

2019-08-03T08:45:31.040Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied

2019-08-03T08:45:31.042Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
    at Channel._discover (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:1272:11)
    at async Channel._initialize (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:291:32)
    at async Channel.initialize (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:244:14)
    at async Network._initializeInternalChannel (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:105:5)
    at async Network._initialize (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:130:3)
    at async Gateway.getNetwork (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/gateway.js:287:3)
    at async main (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/query.js:33:25)
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
    at Channel._discover (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:1272:11)
    at async Channel._initialize (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:291:32)
    at async Channel.initialize (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:244:14)
    at async Network._initializeInternalChannel (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:105:5)
    at async Network._initialize (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:130:3)
    at async Gateway.getNetwork (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/gateway.js:287:3)
    at async main (/home/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/query.js:33:25)

Comment: me too, happened after my Mac crashed and I had to startFabric.sh javascript again, any solution already?

Answer (score 4):

try removing the wallet and re-enrolling the admin and user. In the /fabcar/javascript directory:

```
rm -r ./wallet
node enrollAdmin.js
node registerUser.js
node query.js
```

If that doesn't work, you can try the instructions in:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html
and stop the network (in the /first-network directory):

```
./byfn.sh down 
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep fabcar | awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

this can happen due to the peer leaving the channel or some error related to it.

try to list the peers that are in the channel and see if yours is there

`peer channel list`

If not add again

`peer join channel -b <my-channel-name>.block`